Import Flutter no such module 'Flutter' despite no issues found with flutter doctor
I'm currently working on a Flutter project and encountering an issue with the import statement for the Flutter module. Despite running flutter doctor and getting no issues, I continue to see the following error:
import Flutter No such module 'Flutter'

Here are the steps I have tried so far to resolve this issue:

Deleted and reinstalled the Pods using pod install.
Added the path to the Flutter bin directory.
Cleaned the build using flutter clean and rebuilt the project.

Despite these attempts, the error persists.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on what I might be missing?
Thank you for your help!

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
    
  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
  target 'RunnerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

Above is the content of a working Podfile, please review Podfile your project, delete Podfile.lock, run flutter pub get and then pod install --repo-update.
